# How does a typical Stellar end-user distinguish between assets with same 4 or 12 digit code?

Tags: transactions, assets

My understanding is that Assets created on the Stellar Network are identified with the combination of their 4 or 12 digit code plus the issuing address.

I'm imagining a situation where an Asset on the Stellar Network becomes very valuable, and so a lot of copycat Assets get created with the same code. Users would then need to carefully check the issuing addresses of Assets they receive to make sure they're getting the correct one. This seems difficult and problematic.

Is there any infrastructure in the Stellar Network to help end users distinguish between Assets with the same 4 or 12 digit code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the [home domain field](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/accounts.html#home-domain) on the issuing account of the asset, which should be cross-referenced against the stellar.toml field to verify that it really is an asset issued by that domain. That could be displayed to the user instead of the issuer id, and hopefully would be easier to remember to look up that you’ve got the right one.

Answer (score 0):

The Issuer of the asset should be the distinguishing factor between assets issued with the same asset code.

for example, one might value the BTC issued by Kingdom Trust on the network close to that of a Bitcoin, while valuing the BTC issued by an unknown issuer at nothing.